# C linked list head pointing to itself?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

Here is the a code snippet of my addNode method. For some reason my head node is pointing to itself. Whenever I try to print out the contents of the linked list, all I get is my head's contents.

I know about linked lists already, but I was testing to see if we can use direct structs instead of their pointers to use in linked lists.

```
struct Node{
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
};

// Global variables
int numberOfElements = 0;
struct Node* head = NULL;

void addNode(char* inputString){
    struct Node newNode;
    newNode.data = inputString;
    if(numberOfElements != 0){
        newNode.next = head;
    }
    else{
        newNode.next = NULL;
    }
    head = &newNode;
    numberOfElements++;
}
```

P.S. If the error cannot be deduced from here, then I guess error is somewhere else in my code. If so, I can put that in here as well.

Thanks

Comment: Your `struct Node` does not have a `.string` attribute. Would this even compile?

Comment: My bad, a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Firstly, your code declares a local variable `newNode` and attempts to include it into the list.

  Local variables are destroyed when function exits. This is what happens to `newNode` when `addNode` exits. And your list ends up in invalid state - your `head` ends up pointing to nowhere. That's what leads to the behavior you are observing. (The behavior is most definitely undefined when you attempt to print it out.)

  You have to allocate your node objects in dynamic memory to make sure they live "forever" or as long as you want them to.
- Secondly, your node addition logic is unnecessarily overcomplicated. It appears that you always plan to add a new node to the beginning of the list. In this case the `next` field of the new node should *always* be set to point to the former `head`. The entire `if` with `newNode.next = NULL` branch is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Oh thanks, that totally makes sense. But for the second point, if I don't do `newNode.next = NULL`, wouldn't that be a problem? Say I have only 1 element, in which case `newNode.next` may have garbage value right if I don't make it NULL?

Comment: @lufork: You have to always unconditionally set `newNode.next = head;` before modifying `head`. That way you will never have garbage value on `newNode.next`. Initially `head` is null (empty list), meaning that at the very first addition the above will be equivalent to `newNode.next = NULL;`. I.e. it works just like your version, just without all that unnecessary branching. Your entire `if` is equivalent to a mere `newNode.next = head;`.